# Add/Append array to Array

Tags: swift

I have an array

`var userArray = [String:[String:String]]()`

What I am trying to do is to append another array to it. 
Lets say I want to append:

`let appendArray = ["new":["id":"XXXXX"]]`

Using `userArray.append (appendArray)` results to an error.

How can I append the array to the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
var userArray = [String:[String:String]]()
```

IS not an array but a `Dictionary` or Dictionaries.

If you want an Array then

```
var userArray = [[String:String]]()
```

Is an array of dictionaries.

If you want to keep the current dictionaries then you append it by:

```
userArray[String] = [String:String]
```